# Prevent Footer From Covering Content

Tags: html, css

I currently have a landing page with two columns in a row, but when I scroll my photo in the right column does not stay fully visible. The footer is sticky. Does anyone have any advice? I added a paragraph that I left out the original code, that I want wrapped around the (larger) photo in the left column, while the last three photos float right and fall under each other.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.left {
  width: 65%;
}

.right {
  width: 30%;
  height: 1000px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(106, 35, 35);
  padding: 60px 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

footer nav {
  float: left;
}

footer nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer nav li {
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

footer nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="column right">
<img id="" class="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" width="450px" length="450px" /><br>
<p class="paragraph">Author: Hege Refsnes //Today she graduated and we got ta respect that feel me? Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.  Today she graduated and we got ta respect that feel me? Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
  
Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec e
Today she graduated and we got ta respect that feel me? Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.

Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec e
    </p>
    </div>
  <img id="" class="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" width="450px" length="450px" /><br>
  <img id="" class="img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/450" width="450px" length="450px" /><br><br><br>
</div>
<section>
  <footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li> <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="candy.html">Candy</a></li>
          <li> <a href="cakes.html">Cakes</a></li>
          <li> <a href="chips.html">Chips</a></li>
          <li> <a href="merch.html">Merch</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and post a [mre] of your code. We can't troubleshoot code we can't see! :)

Comment: The footer code has been added to the bottom of the css, right above the the html section. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with a sticky footer, i do prefer adding a margin (any px upto 50px) before i call the footer. This ensures that anytime am scrolling to bottom, there is an empty space that will always be left

see example in screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noLSB.jpg)

Comment: I agree. I will add this on, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

u set the position of the footer fixed in css and it is in line 75 of css

just remove position:fixed
form the footer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).